# How to make from textbox div which contains text of that textbox. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I want to create this on my website. The user will input some text into the textbox and after he will press enter the textbox will change into the div and the div will contain the text from the textbox and it will be on the same place where the textbox was and the text box will hide. Is it possible?

Here is what I have now:
HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.3/js.cookie.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text" class="name" placeholder="What's your name?"/>
```

Javascript (inside of HTML file)

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var name = Cookies.get('_username');
                if (name) {
                    $('#name').val(name);
                }
                $('#name').keydown(function(){
                    var inputName = $('#name').val();
                    Cookies.set('_username', inputName);
                })
            });
        </script>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700');
.name{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5vw;
    border: 0;
    outline:0;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    width: 30%;
    color:#000000;
    position:fixed;
    top:60%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `event.which` to indicates when `enter` button was pressed. Also, use `$('#name').hide()` to hide the `textbox`.

Read more about [event.which](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/)
.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#name').keydown(function(e){
         if(e.which==13){
            $('#name').hide();
            $('#text').html($('#name').val());
         }                       
      });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text" class="name" placeholder="What's your name?"/>
<div id="text">

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks but how to make the textbox to hide and display div in the same place where the textbox was?

Answer (score 2):

You could use jquery to achieve that effect. Keep the div hidden initially using css such as `display: none;`, which we will display using js on pressing enter. Let the div and textbox have an id of `div` and `textbox` respectively.

```
$('#textbox').keydown(function(event){
    //Check if enter was pressed
    if(event.which == 13){
        event.preventDefault();
        //Get value from textbox and set to div
        $('#div').text($('#textbox').val());
        //Show div and hide textbox
        $('#div').show();
        $('#textbox').hide();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it's pretty simple using jQuery;

```js
$('#name').keydown(function(e){
   if(e.which == 13) {
      $(".myDiv").text($(".myDiv input").val());
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
 <input id="name" type="text" class="name" placeholder="What's your name?"/>
</div>
```

Now if you want to use cookies so that the user doesn't have to re-enter the info every time I can answer that as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the text box use replaceWith

```
var inputName = $('#name').val();
if(e.keyCode == 13){
    $(this).replaceWith($("<div>").html(inputName));
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wsfqn8y4/)